# Encrypting RAM for increased security?

Tags: encryption, ram

I decided to mount some of my apps in RAM (like Firefox to load faster due to being a resource hog); but, am somewhat concerned that this would give privy access to my RAM content during normal everyday usage if any intrusion attempt is successful. Are there any tools that can be used to encrypt RAM processes/caches and such?

Comment: Relevant links: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8278/os-with-encrypted-ram, http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/264/what-is-the-benefit-with-using-encrypted-ram-memory

Comment: Encrypting your entire RAM is neither really possible without special hardware supporting it, nor would it be very useful, just a lot of effort to set it up and likely notable performance degradation for few security profit.

Don't think about it, better invest some time in general hardening of your system to minimize chances of getting attacked in the first place.